# How can I send data via TCP

Tags: tcp, labview

I have a client front panel that will send whatever button is being pressed over to the server which is listening for the signals. How should I send the signal?

[`block diagram of client`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCQBE.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Event Structure in a While loop to catch the Value Change event on your array and use a custom message to describe which switch was pressed.

If you want to handle multiple arrays of switches, you can create multiple event cases.

[Block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIlQy.png)

Answer (score 1):

[NI's Basic TCP/IP Communication in LabVIEW](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/06/basic-tcp-ip-communication-in-labview.html) is a good place to start. Take whatever data you want to send over TCP and [flatten to string](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/flatten_to_string/). NI also has [a good writeup on the concept of flattening](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvconcepts/flattened_data/). Simply [unflatten from string](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/unflatten_from_string/) on the receiving end.